# Placing <label> text inside the border of a text input

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I'm looking get this code:

```
<form id="first_name">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label>First name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" />
    </div>
</form>
```

To look like this

[image]

minus the colors, checkbox, value, etc. Essentially I want it to look just like a legend tag does in a field set but without either tags and the label inside the border of the text input. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the `background-color` of the page the same as the `background-color` of the input? You could likely just assign the same `background-color` to the `<label>` and make use of `display: block;` and negative margins.

Comment: Try to place the image you're referencing inside the body of the question rather than linking to it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is what you need. You can change the CSS values according to your need. Also important is to set the `background-color` of label to the same color as your form/html.

```css
.form-group{
  padding:10px;
  border:2px solid;
  margin:10px;
}
.form-group>label{
  position:absolute;
  top:-1px;
  left:20px;
  background-color:white;
}

.form-group>input{
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="first_name">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label>First name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Hope this helps :).

Comment: Close but I actually need the text inside of the input in the image. If I place the text over the input and put a background color, the background gets in front of the text. If I don't put a background color, obviously the border is visible through the test.

Comment: Using your code. Was able to come up with a slightly better solution for me by using a very light gradient. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you should add position:relative in .form-group

Answer (score 13):

You can use legend tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Contact</legend>
  Name <input type="text"><br>
  Email <input type="text"><br>
 </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Legend is the way to go in my book.  It's answers the question and is straighforward.

Answer (score 10):

When I look at the answers here, all of them are answered to save the moment, that is, when the background picture changes, the examples made explode, there is no such problem in my example, you can use it as you wish

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Input</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .textOnInput {
            position: relative;
        }
        .textOnInput label {
            position: absolute;
            top: -15px;
            left: 23px;
            padding: 2px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .textOnInput label:after {
            content: " ";
            background-color: #fff;
            width: 100%;
            height: 13px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            z-index: -1;
        }
        label {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 500;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: .5rem;
        }
        .form-control {
            box-shadow: none !important;

        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="col-md-4 mt-5">
        <div class="textOnInput">
            <label for="inputText">Email</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add position relative if you want more than one box and add some padding:

```css
.form-group{
  padding:10px;
  border:2px solid;
  margin:10px;
}
.form-group>label{
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  position:relative;
  top:-20px;
  left:20px;
  background-color:white;
}

.form-group>input{
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="first_name">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label>First name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" />
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Second name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create an input and wrap it inside a fieldset:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>text creator</legend>
    
<input type="text"
        id="text creator"
       class="form-control"
       name="object-creator"/> 
</fieldset>
```

and some basic css to remove the input border:

```
input {
 border:none;
  width:100%;
}
    input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus{
        outline: none;
    }
```

```css
input {
 border:none;
  width:100%;
}
    input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus{
        outline: none;
    }
```

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>text creator</legend>
    
<input type="text"
        id="text creator"
       class="form-control"
       name="object-creator"/> 
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using pure html. It happens automatically when you nest legend tags in fieldsets

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Here is the legend<legend>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<fieldset class="border col-12 pt-0 pb-1 mx-auto  ">
  <legend class="w-auto mb-0">First Name</legend>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="border-0 p-0 mx-auto pl-1" placeholder="abc@gmail.com">
</fieldset>
```

if you are using bootstrap4 play with class and easily solved it its worked for me you can adjust your class like p-1,ml-2.... etc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>first name</legend>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" style="border: none; outline: none; width: 100%; font-size: 18px">
  </fieldset>
```

Try this. It will help you get what you are looking for with minimal coding.