# How to put text within border as google login?

Tags: html, css

I think today google update login **TextBox** to be like the following?
[image]

as you see a border contains text, **which is the best way to do that** using **HTML** & **CSS**?

**Updated:**

StackOverflow already has only one answer on the following link:

[Placing <label> text inside the border of a text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150781/placing-label-text-inside-the-border-of-a-text-input)

but I am searching about the best way to do that.

Comment: Hey man - This question has been asked and answered. I think this is what you are looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150781/placing-label-text-inside-the-border-of-a-text-input

Comment: @DonJuan..i update the question

Answer (score 3):

Use [pseudo elemnt](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) as `:before` to set text

```css
div{
position:relative;
}
input
{
    border: 2px solid #1a73e8;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 15px;
}
div:before{
    content: 'Email or phone';
    position: absolute;
    top: -9px;
    font-size: 13px;
    left: 6px;
    background: white;
    padding: 2px;
    color:#1a73e8;

}
```

```html
<div>
   <input/>
</div>
```

In the same way you can use `<label>`/`<span>` and position it in css:

```css
div{
position:relative;
}
input
{
    border: 2px solid #1a73e8;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 15px;
}
label{
    position: absolute;
    top: -9px;
    font-size: 13px;
    left: 6px;
    background: white;
    padding: 2px;
    color:#1a73e8;

}
```

```html
    <div>
       <label>Email or phone</label>
       <input/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Using :before for this is not accessible, better to use the actual label for this.

Comment: I think it opinion-based  :)

Comment: I don't think it's much opinion-based as we may get into problem with multi language based on your current solution. 
You could put the text to `data-label` to the `div` & retrieved the content using `attr()` inside `content` attribute

Comment: i edit answer... see please

Comment: No, content being accessible is not opinion based. if a screenreader can't access it, it's not accessible. That's not an opinion that's a fact ;-) 
Also @ToanLu suggestion is not accessible, for best results it shoud be the label. And you can totally style the label the same way you styled the :before so no visual drawback here. 

Thanks for the update with the label.

Comment: @cloned I totally agree. My solution will be also a problem while handling the support for blind people using the app on mobile phone.

Answer (score 3):

Using `position:absolute` to label also can do

```css
div
{
    position:relative;
}
input
{
    border: 1px solid #0095ff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 15px;
}
label
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -9px;
    font-size: 13px;
    left: 6px;
    background: white;
    padding: 2px;
    color:#0095ff;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <label>Email or phone</label>
   <input/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using fieldset and minimum css:

```css
      fieldset { border: 2px solid cornflowerblue;}
      legend {padding: 0 10px;}
      label {visibility: hidden; position:absolute;}
      input {border: none; padding: 10px;}
      input:focus {border: 1px solid silver;}
```

```html
<fieldset>
      <legend>Email or Phone</legend>
      <label for="demo">Enter your email or phone here</label>
      <input type="text" id="demo" />
</fieldset>
```